Read one table write to another data race SQL solution
I'm currently learning about database transactions, isolation levels, and SQL in general. I've thought up a problem which involves a potential data race and can't seem to figure out the solution myself.
Lets say that there are two tables, A and B. I want to update the data in table A, and simply copy the updated field over to table B (fantasy scenario). A data race could easily arise like so

query1: write value 10 to table A
query2: write value 20 to table A
query2: write value 20 to table B
query1: write value 10 to table A

now table A has the value 20, although table B has the value 10!
question 1) how do I ensure that these values can stay in sync across the two tables? I'm assuming that I can wrap the operations in a transaction, although I'm not sure which isolation level I should go with (repeatable-reads?), or if there is a better approach in general.
question 2) Is duplicating fields in database generally a bad practice?
Lets say that I have a Persons table and a cars table, where there is a foreign key cars to person, as a person can own many cars. Lets say that I have a price field on the car. If I want to keep track of how much money (in cars) a person has, should I calculate this always via the cars table and foreign key, or should I keep a field within the persons table called money_in_cars and update this every time the cars table is updated??? The later feels wrong, but the former feels like a lot of work each time we want to find something out
question 3) typically, how is an insert if a row does not exist done? is it normally a two step process, with a lookup and then an insert all done within a transaction, or is it normally just one insert statement with something like ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING? What are the pros and cons of either?
Other SQL antipatterns or related information on data races is greatly appreciated!!!

"Is duplicating fields in database generally a bad practice?" -- Not per se. You are talking about data redundancy. Data redundancy can be very helpful to increase the performance of a database since you can place the same data in multiple places to make queries lightweight. However, keeping all copies of the same data consistent can be a small/huge challenge. A small error in your app can produce differences in the copies. Use with care.
